# Natural deduction for equivalence

Tags: propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

We have the following rules 
$$A \equiv B \vdash A \to B$$
$$A \equiv B \vdash B \to A$$
$$A \to B,B \to A \vdash A \equiv B$$
Prove the theorem 
$$\vdash [p \equiv (q \equiv r)] \to [(p \equiv q) \equiv r]$$

Comment: Do you know how to apply the rules ? You have to assume the antecedent and derive the consequent. Then conclude with $\to$-Intro.

Comment: I already have done

Comment: @Афина if you have made progress already, it would be helpful if you put it in the question as well. That way people know with what you're having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $p ≡ (q ≡ r)$ --- premise

2) $r$ --- assumed [a]

3) $p$ --- assumed [b]

4) $q ≡ r$ --- from 1) and 2) by $\equiv$-Elim and $\to$-Elim

5) $p ≡ q$ --- assumed [c].

From 3), 4) and 5) using $\equiv$-Elim twice  and $\to$-Elim twice:

6) $r$

> 7) $(p ≡ q) \to r$ --- from 5) and 6) by $\to$-Intro, discharging [c].

8) $q$ --- from 2) and using the fact that from 4) we have $r \to q$

9) $p \to q$ --- from 3) and 8) by $\to$-Intro, discharging [b]

10) $q \to r$ --- from 2) by $\to$-Intro

11) $r \to q$ --- from 8) by $\to$-Intro

12) $q ≡ r$ --- from 10) and 11)

13) $p$ --- from 12) and using the fact that from 1) we have $(q ≡ r) \to p$

14) $q \to p$ --- from 13) by $\to$-Intro

15) $(p ≡ q)$ --- from 9) and 14)

> 16) $r \to (p ≡ q)$ --- from 2) and 14) by $\to$-Intro, discharging [a]
>
> > $(p ≡ q) ≡ r$ --- from 7) and 15).

Comment: how can you get q in 4 step, if we haven't it in the first and the second once.

Comment: @From 4) $q\equiv r$ we get $r \to q$ and using 2) we get $q$.